# Fill Android Tab with custom pic and/or colour

Tags: android, colors, tabs, fill

Hey all I've created Google's exmaple of a [tab layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

HelloTabWidget.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

}

I know how to create my own icon to use instead of their grey and white microphone, but I can't figure out how to make my custom icon fill the entire tab.  When the tab is selected it's a light grey with my pic in the middle and when not selected its a dark grey with my pic in the middle.  I prefer to have my own pic fill the entire tab, and for more knowledgeable; my own choice in color to fill the tab.

Comment: This is something I really don't like about Android. Standard Tabs aren't beautiful at all and if selected, the text can't be read any more. Creating a custom TabHost like you want to do, is extremely difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setIndicator(View view)` to do more complex things with the Tab Indicator.

Try playing with this...

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);

// Use imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) or
// imgView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) to load
// the image you want into imgView

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator(imgView).setContent(intent);
```

I'm not sure if it's what you want but you can (in theory) use any View class as the Indicator if ImageView doesn't work for you.

EDIT:

I tried...

```
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable();
    bmd = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, although the arists tab turned completely black. The aritsts line in HelloTabWidget now looks like:
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator(imgView).setContent(intent);
             tabHost.addTab(spec);
not sure if thats right, if so how do I reference an image?

Comment: @Clozecall: See the comments in the first code I posted - sorry, I got them wrong they should be imgView.setImageDrawable or setImageBitmap. Also, see my EDIT: for an example.

Comment: I know this will seem very noobish, but I tried: spec = tabHost.newTabSpec ("artists").bmd = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey);
        iv.setImageDrawable(bmd);
            .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec); -----with this line at the top: BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(); ----However i get an error for bmd=,   iv.setImageDrawable, and .setContent, I'm not even sure if I put that line of code in correctly, I've tried different combinations for an hour, but can't get it, sorry.

Comment: Put the three lines of code in my second code block where the three lines of commented code are in my first code block.

Comment: OK so I fixed the problem, I was getting an error on the line with: iv.setImageDrawable(bmd); ---where as "iv" was the error, I changed that to imgView and now it works! All that is left is to customize and play with my custom images. Thanks for your patience MisterSquonk!

Comment: @Clozecall: My apologies - the second code was copy/pasted from my test code where I'd used iv for my ImageView. Glad you have it working now. Using a View for the Indicator seems like a pretty flexible option, good luck with getting it to work the way you want it to.